# Alternate Characterization of Linearity

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, education

This question is prompted by [this video on matrices and linear transformations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE&index=4&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab), which I highly recommend as a pedagogical tool.  In it, the author characterizes linear transformations in the following way (I'm paraphrasing and formalizing)

> Define a *line* in a vector space to be a set of the form $L = \{u + t\,v: t \in \Bbb R\}$
>   for some vectors $u$ and $v$ *(note: $L$ may consist of a single point)*.  That is, $S$ is an affine subspace of dimension at most $1$.
>
> A function $T: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is *linear* if:
>
> 1. $T(0) = 0$
> 2. For any line $L \subset \Bbb R^n$, the image $T(L)$ is a line in $\Bbb R^m$

I like this definition because of its geometric appeal and the fact that it manages to "put the line in linear".

Of course, the traditional definition of a linear map is one which preserves linear combinations.

---

**My Question:**

> 1. How should one prove that a function satisfying this definition preserves linear combinations?
> 2. Can this be proven in a beginner-friendly way?

I'll admit I haven't really banged my head against this one, but here are my thoughts: it is equivalent to prove that a function that satisfies only the *second* condition (i.e. maps lines to lines) is an *affine transformation*, i.e. that it preserves [affine combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_combination).  From there, it would suffice to note that if $T$ is affine, then $x \mapsto T(x) - T(0)$ is linear.

That being said, I don't see a quick way to handle that proof off the top of my head.  Moreover, if this really is the quickest way to reach a proof, it seems that proving this in linear algebra 101 is a bit too ambitious (which is not to say that this fact fails to be pedagogically useful).  I'm guessing a little real-analysis might have to come in at some point.

---

A note for myself and future visitors:

If we are also given that  is bijective, then this is a consequence of the [fundamental theorem of projective geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation#Fundamental_theorem_of_projective_geometry).

Comment: Does this definition generalize to vector spaces over any field? What about modules over a ring? I, too, don't see a quick proof.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick great question, I have no clue

Comment: I'm starting to think this is false. What about $T:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $T(x)=x^3$?

Comment: Or any origin-preserving surjective map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$?

Comment: That's fair... maybe $n=1$ is some kind of exception though.  Then again, maybe the statement doesn't hold.  Can we extend that to an $n=m=2$ counterexample?

Comment: Nothing immediately comes to mind, but my intuition tells me that the algebraic structure of linearity is a lot stronger than this set-theoretic definition.

Comment: If that is the case, I'd be interested in a $2 \times 2$ counterexample

Comment: Are all origin-preserving isometries $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ linear? The first answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59374/example-of-a-non-linear-isometry) gives a nonlinear origin-preserving isometry $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: And I think the first answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107648/non-linear-function-on-mathbbr2-preserving-the-origin-and-maps-lines-onto) gives us a nonlinear line-preserving and origin-preserving map $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick fantastic find!  It seems we need to assume that $f$ is surjective, and that $m=n \geq 2$.  It looks like this is a standard result in algebraic geometry, as stated in NKS's answer.  I'll look further into that when I can.

Comment: It's quite interesting that bijectivity alone ensures the result.

Answer (score 2):

Only a partial answer, but at least something. I will prove the following statement:

> Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are any real vector spaces and that $f:X\to Y$ is so that for any $u,v\in X$ there are $u',v'\in Y$ such that $f(\{u+tv\ |\ t\in\mathbb R\})=\{u'+sv'\ |\ s\in\mathbb R\}$ and $f(0)=0$. Then $f$ satisfies $f(u+qv)=f(u)+qf(v),\ u,v\in X,q\in\mathbb Q$.

The assumption can be rewritten as follows: There are functions $a,b:X\to Y$ and $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that
$$f(u+tv)=a(u)+g(t)b(v),\qquad u,v\in X,t\in\mathbb R.$$

We first obtain from
\begin{align}
0&=f(0+0\cdot v)=a(0)+g(0)b(v), \\
0&=f(0+t\cdot 0)=a(0)+g(t)b(0), \\
0&=f(tv-tv)=a(tv)+g(-t)b(v), \\
0&=f(tv+t(-v))=a(tv)+g(t)b(-v),
\end{align}
that
\begin{align*}
g(0)b(v)&=g(t)b(0), \\
a(tv)&=-g(-t)b(v)=-g(t)b(-v),\qquad v\in X,t\in\mathbb R.
\end{align*}
**Case 1: $g(0)\neq 0:$** Then $b(v)=b(0)$. If $b(0)\neq0$, then $g(t)=g(0)$ and $a(v)=-g(1)b(-v)=-g(0)b(0)$ and $f\equiv0$. If $b(0)=0$, then $a(v)=-g(1)b(-v)=0$ and again $f\equiv0$.

**Case 2: $g(0)=0$:** Then $a(u)=f(u)$ for all $u\in X$. In particular,
\begin{align*}
f(u+tv)&=f(u)+g(t)b(v), \\
f(u+v)&=f(u)+g(1)b(v),\qquad u,v\in X,t\in\mathbb R.\tag{1}
\end{align*}
If $g(1)=0$, then $f(v)=f(0+v)=f(0)=0$ and $f\equiv0$. We therefore assume that $g(1)\neq0$. Then letting $u=0$ in (1) gives $f(v)=g(1)b(v)$. On the other hand, letting $v=-u$ in (1) gives $f(-v)=-g(1)b(v)$ and hence $f(-v)=-f(v)$ and 
\begin{align}
   f(u+tv)=f(u)+\tfrac{g(t)}{g(1)} f(v),\qquad u,v\in X,t\in\mathbb R.\tag{2}
\end{align}
Suppose that $f\not\equiv0$. Then there is some $x\in X$ such that $f(x)\neq0$. From (2) we obtain 
\begin{align}
f((s+t)x)&=\tfrac{g(s+t)}{g(1)}f(x), \\
f((s+t)x)&=f(sx+tx)=f(sx)+\tfrac{g(t)}{g(1)}f(x)=\left(\tfrac{g(s)}{g(1)}+\tfrac{g(t)}{g(1)}\right)f(x)
\end{align}
and consequently $g(s+t)=g(s)+g(t)$ for all $s,t\in\mathbb R$. Thus, $g(q)=qg(1)$ for all $q\in\mathbb Q$ and
$$
f(u+qv)=f(u)+qf(v),\qquad u,v\in X,q\in\mathbb Q.
$$